# spark parquet without metadata will be slower?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

With pyspark, I have stored data into parquet files without metadata. Because of the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not merge metadata: \
    key org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata has conflicting values
```

I have to configure like this:

```
hadoopConf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.setBoolean("parquet.enable.summary-metadata",False)
```

So it doesn't make any metadata file. Without metadata, will it be slower when I make query ? Of course, it will be better if anyone knows how to resolve the error without configure like this.

Comment: having similar issues, found any solution to creating metadata ?

Comment: Any solution to avoid metadata while creating parquet